# Почему не корректно отображается ширина диалога?

Tags: android-sdk, android

Есть `DialogFragment`. В `onResume` выполняю следующий код для изменения ширины диалога:

```
getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(730, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

По нажатию на на одну из внутренних `view` вызываю

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "w = " + getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes().width, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Возвращает 730 верно, но на глаз вижу что меньше места занимает. Делаю скриншот и в Photoshop смотрю размер диалога, получается ~634.

Что я не так понимаю? Почему не корректно отображается ширина диалога?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась установкой

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так попробуйте

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes();
    params.width = 730;
    params.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    getDialog().getWindow().setAttributes((android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams) params);

    super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: Пробовал, тоже самое